# Object ID Turns into 00000 when decoding data into a struct. Golang and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, web, backend

I am trying to get a document from my database. The document contains a list of Members and each member has an ObjectID. When I decode the document the id of each member turns into 000000, while the original document id stays fine.

I look online and I don't think I did anything wrong and this code also worked in the past, but it no longer does.

```golang
type Quiz struct {
    Title   string             `json:"title"`
    ID      primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Members []Member           `json:"members"`
    Owner   primitive.ObjectID `bson:"owner" json:"-"`
    Open    bool               `json:"open"`
}

type Member struct {
    Name     string             `json:"name"`
    Email    string             `json:"email"`
    Password string             `json:"password"`
    Response Response           `json:"response"`
    ID       primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
}

func Get(ID primitive.ObjectID) (Quiz, error) {
    //creates context
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    var q Quiz
    var err = database.DB.Collection("quizes").FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": ID}).Decode(&q)

    if err != nil {
        return *new(Quiz), err
    }
    fmt.Println(q.Members[0].ID) //00000
    fmt.Println(q.Members[1].ID) //00000

    return q, nil
}
```

Here is an example for a document:
[image: document]

Comment: If you don't think you did anything wrong, what are you asking?

Comment: Can you post a document from your database?

Comment: @icza I added an example document.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am asking because this code no longer works.

Comment: I believe you altered the document for information hiding purposes, but do note the document you posted has `_id` properties which are **strings**, not `ObjectId`s. Please make sure this is correct. If this is indeed what you have in your database, then there is your error.

Comment: @icza This is not what i have in my database, this was just a mistake when copying the data to here. Now the post have the correct data.

Comment: Please do not edit the document to look like what we expect but post exactly what you have in the database. For example `ObjectID` is invalid, MongoDB uses `ObjectId`, so that's obviously not the result what MongoDB displays to you, but rather what you edited it to. The reason why I'm asking exact output is because your code works for me, and if you want to find what's wrong, we must be able to see what you have and reproduce your error.

Comment: @icza I Uploaded a screenshot from mongodb compass so there in no misunderstanding.

Comment: OK, your DB looks ok, your code looks OK, the question now is how you print / inspect the returned value? Show the code which prints `000000` ids.

Comment: @icza I added a print call to the function

Comment: OK, this code works for me and doesn't print `0000` ids. So from now, I can't help you more unless you provide a [mcve]. Provide a complete, runnable app that connects to a MongoDB server, inserts a quiz document, then queries it and prints `0000` id in the end. If I can reproduce what you experience, I can tell what's wrong and help you.